# Как реализовать постинг со своего сайта на своей Facebook странице, используя Api Facebook?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-api, facebooksdk, facebook-graph-api

Будет плагин, который юзеры будут устанавливать себе в свой WordPress-проект. Плагин должен постить из вордпресс к себе в Фейсбук ленту или группу.

Гугл подсказал, что это можно сделать создав developer аккаунт + связать со своим аккаунтом. В developer аккаунте дать пермишены на post на страницы у себя. И дальше реализовать функционал.

А что делать, если другой человек поставит себе этот плагин? Ему создавать developer аккаунт, давать пермишены и т.д.?

Может там все проще и я не понял. Подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: Ничего там не проще, всё так и есть. почитайте инструкции к аналогичному плагину https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/

Comment: Спасибо. Если зарегистрировать бизнес аккаунт можно на один аккаунт несколько юзеров подключать ?
Еще видел варинт когда используют мобайл api